# punycode compiles with arrow function and make it impossible to render in ie 11

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, polyfills

this is generated code in vendor.js  for angular 6 app using angular cli

```
 const ucs2encode = array => String.fromCodePoint(...array);
```

the part with => make issue to render in ie 11

and this is polyfills.ts

https://gist.github.com/BehradI/11966c7ccd54e55319490fe60af103be

any idea?

Comment: Hi, did you ever solve this problem? if so, what did you do?

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue as well, thanks to all the comments, here is what i did.

1. I opened the package-lock.json file, I started tracing punycode, apparently it was declared as dependency package multiple times for other node packages
2. it is very clear the uri-js is referring punycode version 2.1.0 or higher which is causing the problem as this version uses es6 rather than es5 so you end up with arrow function that upsets IE

   "uri-js": {
     "version": "4.2.2",

   "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/uri-js/-/uri-js-4.2.2.tgz",

   "integrity": "sha512-KY9Frmirql91X2Qgjry0Wd4Y+YTdrdZheS8TFwvkbLWf/G5KNJDCh6pKL5OZctEW4+0Baa5idK2ZQuELRwPznQ==",

   "dev": true,

   "requires": {
       "punycode": "^2.1.0"
     }
   },

Other suggested to run npm-install punycode@1.1.4 to replace root package, but since I am facing proxy issues due to firewall settings , what i did is I took a backup from the root punycode and replaced it with one located at node-libs-browser which is punycode version 1.1.4. I prefer this approach as I can easily rollback and don't mess my node-modules folder

Boom things started working after on IE

Answer (score 0):

The arrow function (`=>`) cannot be used is IE11 ([check compatibility](https://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions)).

You can replace it with a `function` like this:

```
const ucs2encode = function(array) {
    return String.fromCodePoint(...array);
}
```

Comment: This is not my code , it’s compiled from one of angular dependencies called punycode

Comment: @BehradIzadi Ok, there is an [open issue](https://github.com/bestiejs/punycode.js/issues/86) regarding this: